# Ruby no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String (TypeError)... to_i not working

Tags: ruby, fixnum

I am learning Ruby and attempting to solve the following challenge:

> Write a method that takes in an integer `num` and returns the sum of all integers between zero and num, up to and including `num`.

I've come up with:

```
def sum_nums(num)
    sum = ""
    num = num.to_i
    if num > 0
        while num > 0
            sum = sum + num
            num = num - 1
        end
    end
    if num == 0
        sum = 0 
    end
    if num < 0
        while x < 0
            sum = sum + num
            num = num + 1
        end
    end
    return sum 
end
```

Been getting the Fixnum string error on the 6th line and unable to troubleshoot on my own. I tried converting num into an integer, even though that didn't make sense to me, as I've written similar methods not requiring `to_i`. But completely lost as to the obvious thing that I'm missing.

Comment: You can't add strings and numbers, so, while you may not have used `to_i` before, you also weren't doing something "similar". You were either starting with two numbers, or you were performing string concatenation.

Comment: Just one question: the error message tells you that it needs a string but gets a number, and you try to fix that problem by converting to a number? Why? It tells you that it already *gets* a number, so you know that it is *already* a number, and that is *wrong*, it expects a string instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is a result of trying to add string `""` with number `num`.

Unlike JavaScript, which will try to convert types, Ruby does not allow you to use different types with math operators (unless they are numerical, such as float or integer).

Correct line 2 to say: `sum = 0`.

Comment: @LeeEames: In addition to the comment by @PetrGazarov, think of whether `num = num.to_i` is really what you want. You say that your method takes an Integer. If this is true, there is no reason to apply `to_i`. If this is not the case, i.e. if you method also accepts other data types besides Integer, think about the possible cases, and whether `to_i` is really appropriate. For example, when `num` is given the string `"25abc"`, the conversion `to_i` does not raise an exception, but silently ignores the letters and just returns 25. This might or might not be what you want.